# Why can't ** be used (for recursive globbing) in a npm package.json script, if it works in 'npm shell'?

Tags: npm, sh, zsh, glob, npm-scripts

So I have an example project here with structure like this:

```
wc-npm-test ❯ tree

├── dir0
│   ├── dir0-1
│   │   └── jsfile.js
│   └── jsfile.js
├── dir1
│   ├── dir1-1
│   │   └── jsfile.js
│   └── jsfile.js
├── jsfile.js
└── package.json

4 directories, 6 files
```

Each **jsfile.js** contains 3 lines:

```
console.log("line");
console.log("line");
console.log("line");
```

In package.json I have two scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "wc": "wc -l **/*.js",
    "shell": "echo $SHELL"
  },
```

Now when I use this command typing it directly into the terminal I got a result like this:

```
wc-npm-test ❯ wc -l **/*.js    
       3 dir0/dir0-1/jsfile.js
       3 dir0/jsfile.js
       3 dir1/dir1-1/jsfile.js
       3 dir1/jsfile.js
       3 jsfile.js
      15 total
```

But when I use it as an npm script it gives me this result:

```
wc-npm-test ❯ npm run wc       

> wc-npm-test@1.0.0 wc
> wc -l **/*.js

       3 dir0/jsfile.js
       3 dir1/jsfile.js
       6 total
```

So when it's performed by the npm it only counts files in *dir0* and *dir1* directories, interpreting **/*.js as in all 1 depth folders all .js files. But when typing directly into terminal it is interpreted as usual - all folders and files from that point.

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening?

My default terminal is zsh. Npm is using the same shell, based on these script:

```
wc-npm-test ❯ npm run shell

> wc-npm-test@1.0.0 shell
> echo $SHELL

/bin/zsh

wc-npm-test ❯ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

npm --version 7.5.2

node --version v14.15.0

zsh --version zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)

Comment: Most ways a script starts a shell won't be using zsh, but will instead be using `sh`, which doesn't support `**` at all.

Comment: Note that `echo $SHELL` is not informative in the manner you expect here; it is by no means guaranteed to tell you which shell is actually running. Moreover, interactive and noninteractive shell startup are very different processes -- interactive shells are expected to honor dotfiles and other per-user configuration; noninteractive shells are expected to behave in as predictable as a manner as possible, so it's desirable for them _not_ to follow per-user configuration, not to honor incompatible extensions, etc.

Comment: Anyhow -- `wc` has nothing to do with your question; deciding how to parse `**` is done by the shell _before `wc` is invoked at all_; it's only Windows where the application being started has the ability to control how its command line is parsed from a string -- everywhere else, it's parsed into an array of individual arguments before the OS is told to start the process at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I knew it's not related to wc, I just used it as an example but didn't really know how to name that (so thanks for help). As for "echo $SHELL is not informative" - so how can I know what shell is being used here by node?
And from what I got: it is probably /bin/sh executing this and it is not supporting **, right?

Comment: Yup. Even if `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `zsh` on your machine (I don't know offhand if Apple does this, but it's a usage mode zsh supports), it goes into POSIX compatibility mode when started that way, so it turns off features that differ from standard-mandated behavior.

Comment: Run the following [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-config) command to obtain which [script-shell](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#script-shell) npm is configured to use when running scripts: `npm config get script-shell`. The default shell utilized by npm on _*nix_ is `sh`, _(which doesn't support `**` as @CharlesDuffy notes)_, and `cmd` on Windows. For cross-platform consider utilizing [cli-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-glob) for globbing in npm scripts.

Comment: @VivaceNonTroppo: I would first verify what shell you are actually running here. You can do it by inserting a nonsense-command (I often use a line with a single closing parenthese, which is illegal in most shells). You will get an error message from it, and, if the error message starts with _**zsh** something_, you know that you are under zsh.

Answer (score 4):

The `SHELL` environment variable is the user's preferred **interactive** shell. It is generally not used for scripts, and it should not be, since this is a user preference and there is no particular reason why the user's preferred shell would implement the language of the script.

In the context of scripting, in a Unix-like environment, “shell” specifically means [`sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01), also known as a “POSIX shell” or Bourne-style shell. POSIX sh is based on the historical Bourne shell, but with several minor differences. Bash is (almost) compatible with POSIX sh. Zsh is broadly similar to POSIX sh, but with several differences.

The wildcard `**/` traversing directories recursively is a zsh extension to POSIX sh. This extension is also present in bash and ksh, but not enabled by default. It isn't present in other popular sh implementations such as dash.

In an sh script, to traverse directories recursively, use the `find` command.

Comment: Yeap, it's this (again), here is simple test:

wc-npm-test ❯ cat wc.sh
wc -l **/*.js

wc-npm-test ❯ /bin/zsh wc.sh 
       3 dir0/dir0-1/jsfile.js
       3 dir0/jsfile.js
       3 dir1/dir1-1/jsfile.js
       3 dir1/jsfile.js
       3 jsfile.js
      15 total
wc-npm-test ❯ /bin/sh wc.sh 
       3 dir0/jsfile.js
       3 dir1/jsfile.js
       6 total

Comment: Still I don't know why echo $SHELL returns /bin/zsh in this case?

Comment: @VivaceNonTroppo Because your account uses zsh as the interactive shell (presumably, it's your login shell).

Comment: @VivaceNonTroppo : AFIK, a zsh interactive login shell sets the environment varaible `SHELL`, which means that all sub shells - be they bash, or dash or whatever - also have this settings. At least this seams to be the behaviour on MacOS. Even if this is not built into the shell, it is not uncommon that the administrator defines the SHELL variable in the global startup file (in `/etc`).

Comment: @user1934428 Zsh doesn't set `SHELL`. The login program does.