# tsx could not find directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-tsx

I'm using Node 19 and have a small library using TypeScript and the builtin testrunner. Based on this [Github issue comment](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3902#issuecomment-1217235905) I'm trying to test the .ts files.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": ["es2022", "dom"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "build",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2022"
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["./build"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "tsc --noEmit && node --loader tsx --test test/**/*Tests.ts"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "18.11.9"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "tsx": "3.11.0",
        "typescript": "4.8.4"
    }
}
```

**./test/someTests.ts**

```
import assert from 'assert/strict';
import { describe, it } from 'node:test';

describe('tests', () => {
    it('passes', () => {
        assert.ok(true);
    });
});
```

When running `npm run test` I get the error

> Could not find '/home/.../repository/test/**/*Tests.ts'

Does someone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT:

[See this example project which I have created.](https://github.com/scottwillmoore/node-test-with-typescript)

#### Problem

I haven't tested your environment, but if I had to guess I believe it is your `npm` script which is incorrect:

```
tsc --noEmit && node --loader tsx --test test/**/*Tests.ts
```

On a POSIX system [`npm` will execute the script with `/bin/sh`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#script-shell). The pattern `test/**/*Tests.ts` is not expanded by `node` or `npm` it is up to `/bin/sh` to expand it. However, `**`, also known as `globstar` is not supported by `/bin/sh`, it is not being expanded as you would expect.
The `globstar` is [supported by `/bin/bash`, but must be enabled](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).

#### Solution

I could be wrong, but I believe since `globstar` is not supported, the pattern `test/**/*Tests.ts` becomes `test/*/*Tests.ts` which will only match files in a subdirectory of your `test` folder, such as `test/abc/xyzTests.ts`. If you just wanted to match tests in the root of the `test` folder, you could rewrite the pattern as `test/*Tests.ts`, which would match `tests/xyzTests.ts`, but would not match files in a subdirectory of your `test` folder.

#### Better Solution

It would be better to rewrite the script in a cross-platform manner, instead of relying on platform dependent features in your scripts which is may be unreliable. This way your script should even work on Windows.

There might be an easier way to leverage another package, but I think I would just move it into a JavaScript or TypeScript script.

Change your script to:

```
tsc --noEmit && node --loader tsx runTests.ts
```

Then create a file named `runTests.ts`.

I don't have the time to experiment with a full script, but I expect you would want to use the [`glob` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to get the list of files and the [`child_process` Node API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to then call `node --loader tsx --test ...`.

#### Related

[Why can't ** be used (for recursive globbing) in a npm package.json script, if it works in 'npm shell'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357091/why-cant-be-used-for-recursive-globbing-in-a-npm-package-json-script-if-i)

[Why you should always quote your globs in NPM scripts.](https://medium.com/@jakubsynowiec/you-should-always-quote-your-globs-in-npm-scripts-621887a2a784)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Linux and looking for a simple way to run .ts test files without any workarounds. I'm using this one here `tsc --noEmit && TS_NODE_FILES=true TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true node --test --require ts-node/register $(find ./test -name '*Tests.ts')` but was hoping for an easy solution using tsx

Comment: I would first try to run the test without any pattern with just an explicit file, such as `tsc --noEmit && node --loader tsx --test ./test/xyzTests.ts`, to see if the actual command will just work.

Comment: If that works, could you not just modify your command to become `tsc --noEmit && node --loader tsx --test $(find ./test -name '*Tests.ts')`. I believe this should work, as long as you are okay not being cross-platform as `find` is POSIX specific.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution and started with this one https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcwDYQEZwGZQiOByZNPAbgChRJY4BvOAUwA86BjAZQE8A7ZuAX02y48nCABM6ALmYALYElEB9MNmZ0AzmpKlSzCJzXwwAQxgw6UTnAC8+MwYD0AKkdOAKuphqAdJ62lCqAAUxqbmnAA0cIHm2FCRdjAAYnJ0AAom0moAlNYAfDSkAJDAGFEx0DnURYUw0tgA7vRQsWSFvNrFpYEAhAnJSGkZanAAPiNwfSnptd4DnAi11lY2AAyV1bUNcJx0jQCizdCBAAYAwhAArvLbEPAYwJyicEac7BMew-XAiyFmFnAAEmovzCvGOWVa7SKun08DUxlUrDoxigJjooncBn6gxm1neWKmQy8ACsIA9Anh8BCOowWBxuCcROI4ABaFkoIziKATNQMVkshKA6jwoyI5FGVFmDEebHTTJg6m8CFAA

Comment: The problem is that you will not get the test result output. You will only get an error that the child process crashed

Comment: [See this example repository which I have created.](https://github.com/scottwillmoore/node-test-with-typescript)

Comment: thanks for your effort. I think it's a good cross-platform solution, but it feels like a workaround to me. I will stick to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358752/tsx-could-not-find-directory#comment131276030_74360552 and hope that there will be better approaches in the future