# How to recursively match Typescript test files with NodeJS native testrunner

Tags: node.js, typescript, glob, node-test-runner

NodeJS recently added a [*native* test runner](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html)

I can successfully get it to run typescript tests with `ts-node` or `tsx`

- `node --loader ts-node/esm --test **/*.test.ts`
- `node --loader tsx --test **/*.test.ts`

But one major drawback is the glob pattern (`**/*.test.ts`) is not working as expected. It is only finding `*.test.ts` files down one directory, and is not recursively finding test files in nested directories. I *think* the problem is that node isn't treating `**` as a *recursive* glob pattern.

**edit**: It looks like the testrunner uses [this glob library](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) which may not support that syntax...

- `src/bar.test.ts` is found
- `src/foo/bar.test.ts` is not found

I'd like to be able to put `*.test.ts` files anywhere in my app and have the test script execute them. Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
.
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── dir
│   │   │   └── more-nested.test.ts
│   │   └── nested-example.test.ts
│   └── example.test.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**` is known as *globstar* and is not available on every system.

First possible solution is to use `find` from the root folder to get a list of files matching a specified pattern (it will look in every subfolder) and then run `node --loader tsx --test` for every found file:

`find . -name "*.test.ts" -exec node --loader tsx --test {} ';'`

Another possible solution (reference: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3902#issuecomment-1307124174) is to create a custom script that finds all files and subdirectories using `glob` package and then run tests invoking `node --loader tsx --test ...` with `child_process`.

Check also this: [Why can't ** be used (for recursive globbing) in a npm package.json script, if it works in 'npm shell'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357091/why-cant-be-used-for-recursive-globbing-in-a-npm-package-json-script-if-i)

Comment: @ZachLysobey i've updated my answer with another possible (and probably smarter) solution. I've done only a rapid check, but seems to work well.

Comment: Yea a friend just suggested something similar:

`$ find . -type f -iname '*.test.ts' -print0 | xargs -0 node --loader ts-node/esm --test`